# Dynamically including/excluding arguments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I have an action method that takes a variable number of arguments, like this:

```
action!(:message => message, :photo => photo, :status => status)
```

If an argument is included it must be valid (based on certain criteria), so something like this won't work:

```
action!(:message => nil, :photo => nil, :status => nil)
```

With this in mind I want to be able to only include an argument if it is valid. Naively I know I can do it like this:

```
 if message.valid? && photo.valid? && status.valid?
     action!(:message => message, :photo => photo, :status => status)
 elsif message.valid? && photo.valid?
     action!(:message => message, :photo => photo)
 ...
 end
```

While this works its really ugly and inefficient. Is there a better way to build the right set of arguments for this call?

Comment: It is not taking a variable number of arguments. It is taking a single argument.

Comment: Got it. I hope you can understand how a comma-delimited list can look like multiple arguments to a noob. I'm learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments are just a hash so why not just create a hash object and add what you need to it:

```
args = {}
args[:message] = message if condition
args[:photo] = photo if condition
...

action!(args)
```

Comment: Just tried and works great. I didn't know you can just pass a single hash object in place of its individual key/values.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you validate them inside your `action!` methode ? And return true or false to tell current action whether all records are valid or not.

```
  if action!(:message=>message .......)
     //do something
  else
     //other things
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use metaprogramming:

```
arguments = [:message, :photo, :status].inject({}) do |result, argument|
  object = __send__ argument
  result[argument] = object if object
  result
end

action! argument
```

if `message`, `photo` and `status` are local variables (but not methods) you should use `#eval` instead of `#__send__`